# install pandoc on CentOS using halcyon

Tags: haskell, pandoc

Following a recommendation [here](https://gist.github.com/grownseed/4fd2e91eca829cc039de) I'm trying to install pandoc on a CentOS 6.3 using [Halcyon](https://halcyon.sh/).

```
halcyon deploy pandoc
```

gives this error

```
   *** ERROR: Unexpected command: deploy pandoc
```

So, I tried

```
halcyon install pandoc
```

which gave this:

```
-----> Installing GHC and Cabal
   External storage:                         public
   GHC version:                              7.8.4
   Cabal version:                            1.20.0.3
   Cabal repository:                         Hackage
-----> Restoring GHC directory
   Downloading https://halcyon.global.ssl.fastly.net/linux-centos-6-x86_64/halcyon-ghc-7.8.4.tar.gz... done
   Extracting halcyon-ghc-7.8.4.tar.gz... done, 699MB

-----> Locating Cabal directories
   Listing https://halcyon.global.ssl.fastly.net/?prefix=linux-centos-6-x86_64/halcyon-cabal-1.20.0.3-hackage-... done
-----> Restoring base Cabal directory
       Downloading https://halcyon.global.ssl.fastly.net/linux-centos-6-x86_64/halcyon-cabal-1.20.0.3.tar.gz... done
       Extracting halcyon-cabal-1.20.0.3.tar.gz... done, 13MB
-----> Updating Cabal directory
   Updating Cabal package database... error
   Downloading the latest package list from Hackage
   cabal: /app/cabal/remote-repo-cache/Hackage/00-index.tar19118.tmp: resource
   exhausted
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would advice to first install ghc & cabal with halcyon using the command `halcyon install`. It looks like cabal fails to install (it might be because of a lack of memory). As a note you might have more success with [github issues](https://github.com/mietek/halcyon/issues) for this kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks @PierreR it does seem to be a memory problem, but I'm working on a VM I can't easily manage so having some trouble debugging